# Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure, then $\mu \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) \leqslant \inf_{i \in \Bbb N} \mu(A_i).$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure, then $\mu \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) \leqslant \inf_{i \in \Bbb N} \mu(A_i).$

I'm trying to figure out how this is true. I'm probably confused with the infimum. How should I think about this? I'm trying to get intuition by considering intervals. For example if $(c,d) \subset (a,b)$, then $(a,b) \cap (c,d) = (\sup\{a,c\}, \inf\{b,d\})$, and $\mu((a,b) \cap (c,d)) \leqslant \mu((a,b))$?

Comment: **HINT** For any $i_0$, $\bigcap A_i\subset A_{i_0}$.

Comment: What does this mean? Is $i \le i_0$?

Comment: The intersection of all sets $A_i$ is contained in any of them.

Comment: To prove $a \le \inf_i b_i$ it is enough to show $\forall i\; a \le b_i$.  If you are confused with infimum, prove this first.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the intersection, we have that $\forall k(\cap A_i \subset A_k)$. By the monoticity property of measures, we must then have $\forall k\big(\mu(\cap A_i) \leq \mu(A_k)\big)$.

Now think about the definition of a lower bound; clearly $\mu(\cap A_i)$ is a lower bound on the set $\{\mu(A_k): k \in \mathbb{N}\}$! Then now we think about what an infimum is; it is the *greatest* lower bound, or in otherwords, the infimum must be larger than (or equal to) any other lower bound. So since $\mu(\cap A_i)$ is a lower bound, it is necessarily true that $\mu(\cap A_i) \leq \text{inf}\mu(A_i)$!

I think the intuition for why the result is true must be based on the monoticity property of the measure. By taking the intersection, you are in some way saying you're taking a set that's "smaller" than any of the $A_i$. So then when you measure this set, you expect it to also be "smaller" than any of the $A_i$ individually.